# What does the Atharva Veda say about cows?

Tags: cows, atharva-veda

This article mentions about [cows in Atharva Veda](https://www.academia.edu/16028337/VEDIC_SCIENCE_AND_ENVIRONMENT)

> Cow is believed as theomorphic animal in Atharva-veda.

What does the Atharva Veda say about cows?

Comment: Question [Cow and position of Devas](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9247/3500) can be closed as duplicate of this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Atharvaveda Khanda 9 Suktha 7](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av09007.htm) describes cow as theomorphic  animal.

> Prajapati and Parameshthin are the two horns, Indra is the head, Agni
>   the forehead, Yama the joint of the neck. King Soma is the brain, Sky
>   is the upper jaw, Earth is the lower jaw. Lightning is the tongue, the
>   Maruts are the teeth, Revati is the neck, the Krittikās are the
>   shoulders, the Gharma s the shoulder-bar.His universe is Vāyu, Svarga
>   is his world, Krishpadram is the tendons and Vertebrae. The Syena
>   ceremony is the breast, Air is the region of the belly,Brihaspati is
>   the hump, Brihatī the breast-bone and cartilages of the ribs.
>
> The consorts of the Gods are the ribs, the attendants are ribs. Mitra
>   and Varuna are the shoulder-blades. Tvashtar and Aryaman the
>   fore-arms, Mahādeva is the arms. Indrāni is the hinder parts, Vāyu the
>   tail, Pavamāna the hair. Priestly rank and princely power are the
>   hips, and strength is the thigh.
>
> Dhātar and Savitar are the two knee-bones, the Gandharvas are the legs
>   the Apsarases are bits of the feet, Aditi is the hooves. Thought is
>   the heart, intelligence is the liver, law the pericardium. Hunger is
>   the belly, refreshing drink is the rectum, mountains are the inward
>   parts.Wrath is the kidneys, anger the testes, offspring the generative
>   organ.The river is the womb, the Lords of the Rain are the breasts,the
>   thunder is the udder.
>
> The All-embracing (Aditi) is the hide, the herbs are her hair, and the
>   Lunar Mansions her form. The hosts of Gods are her entrails, man are
>   her bowels, and demons her abdomen. Rākshasas are the blood, the Other
>   Folk are the contents of the Stomach. The rain-cloud is her fat, her
>   resting-place her marrow. Sitting he is Agni, when he hath stood up he
>   is the Asvins. Standing east-wards he is Indra, standing southwards,
>   Yama. Standing westwards he is Dhātar, standing northwards Savitar.
>   When he hath got his grass he is King Soma.
>
> He is Mitra when he looks about him, and when he hath turned round he
>   is joy.When he is yoking he belongs to the All-Gods, when yoked he is
>   Prajāpati, when unyoked he is All.
>
> This verily is omniform, wearing all forms, bovine-formed. Upon him
>   wait omniform beasts, wearing every shape, each one who hath this
>   knowledge.

For Sanskrit verses, see [Atharvaveda Khanda 9 Suktha 7](http://vedicreserve.mum.edu/atharva_veda/atharva_veda.pdf) (Pg No- 311 and 312)