# Do Hindus consume milk products?

Tags: food

I thought people from India, partly due to Hinduism being widespread, would be vegetarian or even vegan. But I've recently been to an Indian restaurant and even though cow meat was not on the menu as expected, there were several items derived from milk products.

So my question is, do Hindus eat milk products?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Hindus eat milk products. [Cow is described as theomorphic animal](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/12487/3500) in Vedas (meaning knowledge) which are highest truths. So, Hindus revere cow as their mother and God. But we consume products like milk, yogurt, ghee, butter. As cow is revered as God and mother, Hindus don't kill Cow and bull for their meat. Cow is also described as Earth many times in Puranas.

Lord Krishna, avatar of Lord Vishnu, [likes butter very much](http://www.vedabase.com/en/kb/9). Milk Products gives [Sattva Guna](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2660/3500) while flesh of any animal gives Tamas Guna. So, some Hindus follow Vegetarian diet.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, absolutely. Hindus consume all kinds of dairy products. Despite the fact that the cow is holy, Hindus domesticate cows and use the cow for milk, but they will not kill the cow for meat.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan what source can we give in this kind of Q? OP is just asking Yes/No to consumption of milk by Hindus. Not sure any scriptural ref. can be provided here.

Comment: @WhisperingMonk Well, the OP is asking whether Hinduism allows dairy products.  Certainly sources can be provided for that.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan that is what I am trying to understand! What kind of sources? you mean some examples from scriptures describing some persons taking milk/milk products like Ghee etc.?

Comment: @WhisperingMonk The same sorts of sources you would cite if a question asked whether Hinduism allows eating meat.