# Are any new writings in the sukta form created recently?

Tags: vedas

I would like to know about any recent literature which were written in the form of `sukta`.

Comment: In order to compose a Sukta , one must be a realised person as well as a poet, a difficult combination to have @kku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [definition of Sūkta](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/shukta), was given below

> **Sūkta (सूक्त)**.—a. ***well-spoken, well-said***;  Sūkta is a Sanskrit compound consisting of the > terms **su** and **ukta** > (उक्त).
>
> Sūkta (सूक्त) refers to one of the three principle styles found in
>   Sanskrit literature.—Sūktas are the hymns of the Vedas, these are
>   ***poetic compositions*** set to various different metres, **some are
>   comprehensible** while others are **cryptic and need interpretation**.

---

So the basic requirements for composition a Sūkta (सूक्त) are:

1. He/She should be SPIRITUALLY ELEVATED person
2. Must have heard the Divine sayings i.e, he/she must be a [drastha](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/drashta)
3. He/She must be a poet, who can compose hymns in cryptic language.

---

A rare combination for composing a Sūkta (सूक्त).

We have many SPIRITUALLY ELEVATED persons in recent past, like Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa, Sri Nirmala Devi/Anandamai Ma/Sri Ramana Maharshi, etc.

However, composing a hymn or Sūkta (सूक्त) requires the 3rd quality, ie., to be a poet.

That is why we could not witness a Sukta now a days.

---

However, it does not mean that there were no seers in our period.

Sri kaavyakantha Ganapati Muni composed [Uma Sahasram](http://www.arunachala-ramana.org/forum/index.php?topic=3657.0).  Out of 1000 verses that were proposed, 700 were composed on his own, but the remaining were composed in the last few hours before the deadline he had put for himself, out of the grace of divine personality Sri Ramana Maharshi.

> Kavyakanta sat before Bhagavan Ramana around 8 pm.  Bhagavan was
>   sitting in front of him, with His eyes closed.  By midnight Kavyakanta
>   Ganapati could dictate the remaining 300 verses!   Bhagavan Ramana
>   then opened His eyes and asked:  ***Nayana! Have you taken down
>   everything?***  Kavyakanta could not control his tears and prostrated
>   before Him and sang an extempore sloka on his Guru's grace!
>
> Kavyakanta Ganapati made several changes later in the first 700
>   verses, but he never touched the last 300 verses.

It was stated that **Uma Sahasram** has miraculous [healing powers](https://surasa.net/uma/).