# Is there any reference to how vedic mantras revealed to Rishis?

Tags: vedas, rishi

I would like to know how it happened . 
1) Like did Rishis , for instance Vishvamitra or Vashishta would give up attachments and go to forests to do penance and then , for how many tens of years they did penance ?

2) How did they come to know a vedic verse came to them ? what was the process of revelation like ?

3) How much portion they got each time ? like just a mantra for 10 years of penance or entire mandala of rigveda ?

Comment: You can go through this answer( https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36794/3869) for understanding how a mantra created@Curious

Comment: THERE will not be any time limit for getting revelation of a Mantra.  Everything rests with the Almighty @Curious

Comment: Little confused by your question. Are you asking how were the vedas revealed or how were mantras revealed to rishis? Different answers.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma While the first part asks what they did to receive them, the second is asking what that reception was like. Hopefully OP will modify the question to reduce its scope after which point we will know which question he wants answered, the duplicate or something new.

Comment: hello. sorry for late reply . Yes @RubelliteYakṣī you're right