# Why Cow is considered as GOD in Hinduism?

Tags: belief, animals, cows

I want to know the reason why Cow is considered as GOD in Hinduism?

Comment: @GopalBiswas - Yes the answer is already present in the previous post although the wording of your question is somewhat different. Also if you are interested [This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19676/5620) answer of mine is also related. So I am voting to close the post

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Yes, both the questions looking similar. Thanks for the reference topic which you mentioned in comment.